# Claws Mail keeps crashing

Tags: 14.04, email, crash, claws

I am using Claws Mail v.3.9.3, on Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit). It has been working fine for years up until last week. Now, when I check an email account it shows it downloading the email and then, when done, it crashes, with no email downloaded.

These are the errors I receive in the`apport.log`

```
ERROR: apport (pid 12562) Mon Aug 20 15:27:02 2018: called for pid 12536, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 12562) Mon Aug 20 15:27:02 2018: executable: /usr/bin/claws-mail (command line "claws-mail")
ERROR: apport (pid 12562) Mon Aug 20 15:27:02 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 12562) Mon Aug 20 15:27:24 2018: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_claws-mail.1000.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 12708) Mon Aug 20 15:33:16 2018: called for pid 12694, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 12708) Mon Aug 20 15:33:16 2018: executable: /usr/bin/claws-mail (command line "claws-mail")
ERROR: apport (pid 12708) Mon Aug 20 15:33:16 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 12708) Mon Aug 20 15:33:16 2018: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
[Started program from terminal:]
ERROR: apport (pid 12787) Mon Aug 20 15:35:44 2018: called for pid 12775, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 12787) Mon Aug 20 15:35:44 2018: executable: /usr/bin/claws-mail (command line "claws-mail")
ERROR: apport (pid 12787) Mon Aug 20 15:35:44 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 12787) Mon Aug 20 15:35:44 2018: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

In the`syslog`I get this:

```
lee-desktop rtkit-daemon[1842]: Successfully made thread 12529 of process 4351 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 2.
Aug 20 15:25:40 lee-desktop rtkit-daemon[1842]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 20 15:27:01 lee-desktop kernel: [21592.579522] claws-mail[12536]: segfault at f947894 ip b108b8d5 sp bfa36e80 error 6 in tnef_parse.so[b1085000+c000]
```

The `/var/crash/_usr_bin_claws-mail.1000.crash` listed above [is located here](https://leeunderwood.org/downloads/claws-mail.crash.txt).

Any ideas of what the problem is? I've been using Claws Mail for many years and really like it. I am now having to use Evolution; I've tried Thunderbird, and checking mail via browser -- none of which I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally removed the program & purged the files [using the method here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/precise/claws-mail?action=remove)

I reinstalled it and it works fine and all my data is still there.